# Apple TV and external monitor to show full screen

Tags: objective-c, fullscreen, airplay, apple-tv

I am trying to display my uiview on monitor via passing through apple TV.

When I just directly connect my iPad and monitor, I can display full screen on that monitor. It is because I can take maximum size like this.

```
self.availableModes = [extScreen availableModes];

    self.extScreen.currentMode = [availableModes lastObject]; // should be largest
```

However, when I connect my Apple TV to monitor via HDMI cable and iPad connect to apple TV wirelessly, I only get 1 size which don't give full screen on monitor. 
**UIScreenMode: 0x20857ef0; size = 1280.000000 x 720.000000**

I would like to know how to do so that I can show my uiview with full screen on my monitor using Apple TV via Air Play.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Apple TV2 or AppleTV3?  Apple TV 2 is only 720p (1280x720)  Apple TV 3 is 1080p (1920x1080)